# Show that any connected graph $G$ satisfies $\lvert E(G)\rvert \geq \lvert V(G)\rvert -1 $

Tags: graph-theory, induction

> Show that any connected graph $G$ satisfies $\lvert E(G)\rvert \geq \lvert V(G)\rvert -1 $ by induction on the number of edges.

My attempt:

1. Base Case: For any connected graph $G$ let number of vertices $= 1$
   so $0 \geq 1-1$ which is true.
2. Now i'm not really sure what to do here.

Answer (score 3):

Try removing a vertex. How many edges are left? How many disappeared?

If the graph that remains after removing the vertex is connected, then by induction there are at least $|V(G)|-2$ edges remaining since there is a connected graph with $|V(G)|-1$ vertices, and we would have had to remove at least one edge in removing our vertex, so $G$ has at least $|V(G)|-1$ edges.

If it is not connected, it is the disjoint union of some number of connected components, say $k$. By induction, the sums of the number of edges in these remaining components is at least $(|V(G)|-1)-k$. In order for $k$ components to have been created by removing the vertex, we would have had to remove at least $k$ edges. Thus the original graph has at least $(|V(G)|-1)-k+k=|V(G)|-1$ edges.

Comment: Doesn't that depend on the graph? For example if you have a triangle graph and you remove 1 vertex 2 edges are removed and 1 is left

Comment: But is the graph still connected?

Comment: @Rafflesiaarnoldii That again depends on the graph, in my triangle graph example it is, but in other examples it might not be

Comment: See edit above.

Comment: @MattS you said the result easily follows by induction, would by mind expanding on that bit? Sorry, I still don't fully understand.

Comment: See second edit above.