# Prove that for graph $G$, $|E(G) \ge |V(G)|−1 $ implies that $G$ is connected

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

How do we prove that for graph $G$,

> If $G$ is acyclic and $|E(G)| \ge |V(G)|−1$ it implies that $G$ is
>   connected?

I saw that there is a similar question about a proof going the other way here:

[Show that any connected graph $G$ satisfies $\lvert E(G)\rvert \geq \lvert V(G)\rvert -1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1014378/show-that-any-connected-graph-g-satisfies-lvert-eg-rvert-geq-lvert-vg)

I would think that the proof would be similar, but I'm having a very hard time with it.

Another question that I have is how to prove that for graph $G$, if $G$ is connected and $|E(G)| \ge |V(G)|−1$ it implies that $G$ is acyclic? I would assume that this should be very similar, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: In your last question, "if $G$ is connected and $|E(G)|\ge|V(G)|-1$ it implies that $G$ is acyclic?", was $\ge$ a type for $\le$? If not, I have a counterexample with $|E(G)|=|V(G)|=3.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let suppose that G is a not connected acyclic graph and $\lvert E(G)\rvert \geq \lvert V(G)\rvert -1$

this will lead to contradiction, G is acyclic if there is an eadge between v1 and v2 then for every thing v2 is connected to there is no path from that vertex to v1 since acyclic dissallow cycle and the same happens for all vertices and since the G is not connected there exists a vertex with incoming and outgoing degree equals to 0, then $|E(G)|<|V(G)|-1$ .

which proof that 
 **if g is acyclic and |E(G)|≥|V(G)|−1 it implies that G is connected** By contradiction.